# Network UPS Tools (NUT) causing UPS to Reboot?

Tags: linux, debian-jessie, ups, nut

I have NUT upsmon 2.7.2 installed on an OrangePi One running Armbian 5.25 (which is Debian jessie). It is setup to monitor my Tripp Lite SmartOnline SU3000RTXLCS2U using the usbhid-ups driver and communicate to the server when it should shutdown or power up. I can successfully get my UPS information running the `upsc` command, so I thought all was working well.

One issue I cant figure out is why my UPS reboots (and cuts power to everything connected to it) when I issue a reboot command to the OrangePi. I can send it a shutdown command and it shuts down without messing with the UPS. When I run the `upsc` command, I can see:

```
ups.timer.reboot: 0
ups.timer.shutdown: -1
ups.timer.start: 0
ups.vendorid: 09ae
ups.watchdog.status: 0
```

My guess was that the upsmon server sends the UPS the reboot command before the service stops. I see that `ups.timer.shutdown: -1` which makes me think that the UPS is set to ignore shutdown commands, and `ups.timer.reboot: 0` means that the UPS is set to reboot immediately on receiving a reboot command. Is this correct? Do I need to set `ups.timer.reboot: -1` or something? And how would that be done?